# Trouble setting a value using XML Etree

Tags: xml, set, elementtree

I am trying to change the value of a node from an XML file.

I am using XML Etree/Element Tree.

My code is the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import array

tree = ET.parse('Beckhoff ELM37xx.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

global xdevice

for Descriptions in root.findall('.//Descriptions'):
    xdescriptions = Descriptions.find('Devices')
  
for Devices in root.findall('.//Devices'):
    xdevices = Devices.find('Device')

for Device in root.findall('.//Device'):
    xdevice = Device.find('Name').text
    print(xdevice)

##tree.write('Beckhoff ELM37xx.xml')
```

With `xdevice`, I am getting the information I need displayed, it's 10 elements.

```
ELM3702-0000 2Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision
ELM3702-0000 2Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision
ELM3704-0000 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision
ELM3704-0000 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision
ELM3704-0001 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision, LEMO
ELM3704-0020 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision, calibrated
ELM3704-0020 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision, calibrated
ELM3702-0101 2Ch. Ana. Input +/-60V, +/-20mA, TC, RTD, Bridge Measuring (SG), IEPE, 24 bit, high precision, isolated channels
ELM3704-1001 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-10V, TC, 24 bit, high precision
ELM3704-1001 4Ch. Ana. Input +/-10V, TC, 24 bit, high precision
```

I would like to understand how to change the first value using `set`, since indexing doesn't work, it gives back the letter E for each iteration. I want to understand how to store this values into a list or a tuple, in order to be able to modify it (or modifying it directly but just one value of the list at will).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Beckhoff ELM37xx.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
Devices = root.findall('.//Device')
nametag1 = Devices[0].find('Name')
nametag1.text = 'Blanqui'

for Device in root.findall('.//Device'):
    xdevice = Device.find('Name').text
    print(xdevice)
    
tree.write('Beckhoff ELM37xx.xml')
```